# $4x^2 + 2y^2 - 2y = 0$ $\implies 8x^2 + (2y-1)^2 = 1$ By completing the square (how)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Goal: $4x^2 + 2y^2 - 2y = 0$   $\implies 8x^2 + (2y-1)^2 = 1$

my attempt:

$4x^2 + 2y^2 - 2y = 0$

$4x^2 + 2(y^2 - y) = 0$

completing square formula

$(y+d)^2 + e = y^2 + 2dy + d^2 + e$

$2dy = -1(y) \implies d = -\frac{1}{2}$

$e+d^2 = 0 \implies e = -\frac{1}{4}$

So.

$4x^2 +2((y-1/2)^2 - 1/4) = 0$

$4x^2 + 2(y-1/2)^2 - 1/2 = 0$ [Factored $2$ in]

$8x^2 + 4(2y-1)^2 = 1$ [Multiplied everything by $2$ to get the $1$]

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: very last line, your $(y-1/2)^2$ term somehow has been turned into $(2y-1)^2$, you were meant to have $4(y-1/2)^2$ then you can put the 4 in and you get what you need

Comment: Oh... thank you!

Comment: It would be easiest to begin by multiplying by $2$, i.e., $$4x^2+2y^2-2y=0\implies8x^2+4y^2-4y=0\implies\cdots$$ In that way you can avoid having to fuss with fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You double dipped.  You were right to multiply by $2$, which turns the $2(y-1/2)^2$ term to either $4(y-1/2)^2$ or $(2y-1)^2$.  Putting $2(2y-1)^2$ was too many factors of $4$.

Answer (score 1):

In the very last step: Multiplying $2(y−\frac12)^2$ by 2 gets you **either**

$4(y−\frac12)^2$

**or**

$(2y−1)^2$

You incorrectly did both.

Answer (score 1):

$$4x^2 + 2((y-1/2)^2-1/4) =  0 $$

means

$$4x^2 + 2 (y-1/2)^2 - 1/2 = 0 $$

or

$$8x^2 + 4 (y-1/2)^2 - 1 = 0$$

or

$$8x^2 + (2y-1)^2 = 1$$

since $2^2=4$.

Answer (score 0):

You are intended to notice that $(2y-1)^2=4y^2-4y+1$ and that doubling your original equation will give the proper combination of $y^2$ and $y$
$$4x^2+2y^2-2y=0\\8x^2+4y^2-4y=0\\8x^2+4y^2-4y+1=1\\8x^2+(2y-1)^2=1$$
From your next to last to last line, when you multiply $2$ inside the square you need a factor of $4$ from in front of it.